# Cocos2d-x SetFrameSize make screen touch event wrong position

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, screen-size

I use visual studio to implement my Win32 game project, but because I will port it to android platform later, so in AppDelegate class, I use setFrameSize to make window screen be like a mobile screen as below:

```
glview->setFrameSize(600, 900);
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(320, 480, ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_WIDTH);
```

But I got problem when implementing menu items, if I use setFrameSize function, when I touch to menu item, they does not work because their visual position is diffent from thier real position. If I comment out the set frame size command, menu items work correctly, but my screen too big and is very difficult for me to develope mobile game. Does anyone know why this problem come to me and how to resolve it? Thank alot.

Edit: I use visibleSize  to set position for my menu items. It seem to not the same as what I want because when I set position of sprite is 3/8 of screen height ( bottom up), it become 1/2 of screen height ( bottom up).

Comment: Did you look at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support document? It explains how to support multi resolution in cocos2d-x